# \include-ed variables in lilypond-book environments don't expand

Tags: lilypond

I'm typesetting some music exercises using lilypond within TeX. Plain code seems to work fine, but I have a lot of code which is reused so I've tried to set up variables. The variables seem to get picked up but not expanded.

MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = LilyPond-Book
% !LILYPOND tex = xelatex
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{lilypond}
{
  \include "lilypond-variables.ly"
  \time 2/4
  \grace { g''32 } g'4  \Ggrace a'4  \Ggrace b'4  \Ggrace c''4
  \Ggrace d''4 \Ggrace e''4 \Ggrace f''4         g''4
          a''2         g''4         f''4 \Ggrace e''4
  \Ggrace d''4 \Ggrace c''4 \Ggrace b'4  \Ggrace a'4
  \Ggrace g'4
  \bar "||"
}
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

Included file `lilypond-variables.ly`:

```
Ggrace = { \grace { g''32 } }
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the 'hard-coded' g grace note is fine, but the ones which should be produced by `\Ggrace` simply don't appear.

I've tried `\include` (with quotes as specified in the Lilypond documentation) and `\input` (quotes as above and braces), and before this I tried standard `\newcommand`s within the TeX code but the result was the same.

As I have many, many grace note combinations this is quite a big problem. I had them all hard-coded originally, and thought I'd make future coding less painful and error prone.

Using macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73) and TL 2016.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Done. The original comment has been removed however so my response doesn't make much sense by itself, so I've removed it also.

Comment: I think this is a pure Lilypond problem.

Comment: @egreg You may be right. I'm now of the opinion that it's the lilypond-book python script which is to blame (I *thought* it might be related to the engine). The variables are recognized, but then not applied. Should we close this here?

Comment: @K.G.Feuerherm I don't think we can do something on the TeX side about the problem.

Comment: @egreg Well... If there was a way to force expansion of `\newcommand{\Ggrace}{...}` *before* lilypond-book gets invoked, it would work; but I don't know whether that's possible? Else, I agree.

Comment: As far as I know, `lilypond-book` strips off everything not in a `lilypond` environment, typesets with `lilypond` the music pieces and produces graphic files that are then included during the run of LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if the `\include` is moved outside the braces, the code works just fine, as follows:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = LilyPond-Book
% !LILYPOND tex = xelatex
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{lilypond}
\include "lilypond-variables.ly"
{
  \time 2/4
  \grace { g''32 } g'4  \Ggrace a'4  \Ggrace b'4  \Ggrace c''4
  \Ggrace d''4 \Ggrace e''4 \Ggrace f''4         g''4
          a''2         g''4         f''4 \Ggrace e''4
  \Ggrace d''4 \Ggrace c''4 \Ggrace b'4  \Ggrace a'4
  \Ggrace g'4
  \bar "||"
}
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

So it was in fact a Lilypond issue as suggested by @egreg (with thanks, and to the colleague on the Lilypond list who pointed to the solution).